# Can a Solenoid be driven from one of the pins of a Servo controller?

Tags: microcontroller, driver, servo, pins, solenoid

Would it be possible to operate a solenoid (e.g. this [Plastic Water Solenoid Valve - 12V - 1/2" Nominal](http://www.adafruit.com/products/997), suggested for use with "a TIP120 or N-Channel power FET with a 1N4001 kickback diode to drive from a microcontroller pin.") from one of the pins of a Servo Controller (e.g. this [Pololu Micro Maestro 6-channel USB Servo Controller](http://www.robotshop.com/en/pololu-micro-maestro-6-channel-usb-servo-controller-assembled.html?utm_source=google&utm_medium=base&utm_campaign=GoogleUSA))?

[image: Pololu Micro Maestro 6-channel USB Servo Controller]

Or am I overthinking it- for my solenoid ought I just use whatever relay I need on top of a simple breakout board such as this:

[image: USB Mini Breakout Board]

Comment: Neither of the parts pictured is particularly useful.  The servo driver merely converts USB commands to PWM signals, it lacks any power semiconductor to drive a motor which could be reurposed for a solenoid (the drive transistors are inside the servos you connect to it).  The breakout board has no electronics, only wires, so that won't work either.  USB relay modules are sold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go for the simple relay control. Try this one from the same site you linked to:
http://www.robotshop.com/en/devantech-2-channel-usb-relay.html

The servo driver ouputs a pulse train to control the servo position. Seems like an overcomplicated way of doing things by modifying it as an on/off controller.

Comment: The breakout board looks to be for USB signal and power only ie no control signal is available... you still need something to talk to the PC over USB.

Comment: Ooops, got confused by the microcontroller text in the question.

Comment: I would like to know what the IO or 1D or ID pad is in the picture... it could be the (missleading named) "1 wire" port.... Without knowing what it is we could be looking at the simplest solution or bad solution or no solution...

Comment: @Spoon The ID pin is for telling a USB otg device (like a phone) to act as a host rather than a device.  That breakout is unsuitable as it has no electronics to implement the USB signalling or protocol or interpret commands.